# How can I use grep command in bash script to search a line but print only some part of the line and specifically excluding the word itself?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, grep

I wish to list all header files in a C file using a Bash script

```
#include <stdio.h> // in output it should print stdio.h
```

Comment: Do you really need the `ubuntu` tag for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd probably use `sed`:

```
sed -n -e 's/^#include[[:space:]]*[<"]\([^>"]*\)[>"].*/\1/p' "$@"
```

and I might put a `[[:space:]]*` unit before the `#` and after the `#` to allow for optional spacing.  That covers the vast majority of cases.  You can have

```
#define STDIO_H <stdio.h>
#include STDIO_H
```

and the script won't spot that.  You could also have a backslash-newline in the material and the script won't spot that, either.  And it doesn't handle comments embedded in the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // This one is detected OK
/*#*/#/*$*/include\
/\
* This one is not!
*\
/\
<stdlib.h>
```

OTOH, I don't care.  Anyone who wrote code like that second `#include` except as a torture test for the compiler deserves to be…treated with disdain and not allowed to check their code into the version control system.  (Note: I forebore from using trigraphs in that code.)

Comment: Disappointed that you decided to skip the example with trigraphs! ;)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: If you want something complex, consider `#include <./*same*/header.h>`; how much of that is comment?  Similarly `#include <.//header.h>`.  And, for grins: `#include <./*same/header.h>`, not to mention `#include <c:??/??/windows??/??/header.h>` (there you are — some trigraphs!).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any bash script. A grep one-liner will do this job.

```
grep -oP "#include\s*<\K[^>]*" file
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. So that the output won't contain `#include<` part.

Comment: People are sensible to write a Bash script to encapsulate this task if it is going to be done very often (say more than twice).  Especially if the regex is moderately complex.  Why are you matching up to a single quote instead of a `>`?